# Numerical Methods, Neville method of aproximation and Lagrange interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

So I have a set of points `x = [0 2 7 8]` and `y = [3 0 15 7]` respectively. I tried to approximate it using Neville Method and the formula $P_{i,j}=\frac {(x - x_j)P_{i, j - 1} + (x_i - x)P_{i + 1, j}}{x_i - x_j}$ for $0\leq i \leq j \leq 3$ and $P_{i, i} = f(x_i)$ for $i = 0, 1, 2, 3$, and I wanted to approximate it at the point $x = 5$ and got the approximation with Neville's $14.429$ and with Lagrange interpolation using formula:

$$P_n(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n f(x_i) \prod_{k = 0, k \neq i}^{n}\frac {x - x_k}{x_i - x_k}$$

and got the approximation of $P_3(5) = -11.289$. Why they are so different?

Comment: Neville's Method  works well for equally spaced points, this is not the case here. They would produce the same result if the points are equally spaced.

Comment: thank you!!! so the lagrange interpolation polynomial it s good for points with any kind of distance between them, right?

Comment: Why Neville's method works well for equally spaced points?

Comment: I am not expert in this, but I got my information from this book that I used to study sometime ago. See page 204 Here if you would: https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=VKs7Afjkng4C&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=Neville+vs+lagrange&source=bl&ots=JrcwMkusLM&sig=ACfU3U2cfVP40rrgN0ZONwJbIKGY3prjIw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilrq3Zy7biAhViXRUIHTNJD9o4ChDoATACegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=Neville%20vs%20lagrange&f=false